# Show that a finite subset of the reals exists whose sum is greater than some real number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is another problem I'm having difficulties with.
I'd love to show what I've tried, but I don't even know where to begin.

Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ be some function. Show that for any positive real number ε there exists a finite subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that the sum of {$f(x) | x \in A$} is greater than ε.

One hint has already been given which is to think of the sets {$x | f(x) > \delta$} for $\delta > 0$.
Still no idea what to do.

Can someone please give me another hint, or some direction?

**EDIT**: On a side note, how does this correlate with infinitesimals? The first thing that comes to mind is to consider extreme examples, like $f(x) = \gamma$ when $\gamma$ is an infinitesimal number. There's no way that for any $A$ can be finite. I suppose infinitesimals aren't really real numbers?

Comment: Thanks! I meant that the sum of the elements of $A$ after $f$ is applied to them is greater than ε.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider sets $A_n=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}$. Show that at least one of $A_n$ is infinite.

As for your question about infinitesimals: **no**, there aren't any infinitesimals in $\Bbb R$, and this can be proven using [least-upper-bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) of real numbers: suppose infinitesimals existed. Then they would form a nonempty, bounded set, so it would have a supremum $c$. Then $\frac{c}{2}$ would be and $2c$ wouldn't be an infinitesimal, say $2c>\frac{1}{N}$ for $N\in\Bbb N$. But then $\frac{c}{2}>\frac{1}{4N}$, so $\frac{c}{2}$ isn't infinitesimal, leading us to contradiction.

Comment: Took me a bit of time to glue everything together, but I did it. Thanks.